# Swapping lists trouble with last value, c++

Tags: c++, list, pointers, this, swap

I am trying to swap the values between two lists, it uses a member function of a custom List class i created called ListNum which is friends with a node class and an iterator class. I am able to swap them but I keep getting a weird error I am not sure how to solve. On the last value for the second list I get an error when I try to implement it.

I simply insert after the first iterator for both the lists and then delete that element, the iterator automatically goes to the next value of the list after it deletes. On the last erase call it checks to see if the value being deleted is 
"last". On the second list the value is "last" but when it checks in the if statement of "erase" this call fails and I get a BAD_ACCESS Error. Basically trying to assign a null pointer that results in the error

The value is 6 and it is last but fails the if statement for last. I am not sure if this has to do that the first list I needed to create a pointer to this while the second list was passed as reference.

Here is my code.

```
int main(){

    list1.push_back(1);
    list1.push_back(2);
    list1.push_back(3);

    list2.push_back(4);
    list2.push_back(5);
    list2.push_back(6);

    list1.swap(list2);

 return 1;
}
```

This is the swap member function that I am trying to implement

```
void ListNum::swap(ListNum& list2){

    ListNum* list1 = this;

    IteratorNum end1 = list1->end();
    IteratorNum end2 = list2.end();

    IteratorNum start1 = list1->begin();
    IteratorNum start2 = list2.begin();

    while(!start1.equals(end1) && !start2.equals(end2)){

        list1->insert(start1, start2.get());
        list2.insert(start2, start1.get());
        start1 = erase(start1);
        start2 = erase(start2);
    }  
}
```

The code fails on the last run of the while Loop here in the if statement (remove == last)

```
IteratorNum ListNum::erase(IteratorNum iter){

    assert(iter.position != NULL); //check that erase is not null

    NodeNum *remove = iter.position;
    NodeNum *after = remove->next;
    NodeNum *before = remove->previous;

    if(remove == first)
        first = after;
    else
        before->next = after;

//FAILS HERE, 6 is last int value but it doesn't pass this test. List 1 passes but list 2 does not...
    if(remove == last) //erasing at end of ListNum
        last = before;
    else
        after->previous = before;

    delete remove;

    IteratorNum r;
    r.position = after;
    r.container = this;
    return r;

}
```

Comment: Please extract a minimal example, see the posting guidelines.

Comment: Why are you doing it this way? Swap start and end pointers. Two lines of code. Impossible to make a mistake.

Comment: @n.m. I am not following, how would swapping them help?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I don't know how I can make it a minimal example, people need to see the erase code to see how it works and where it is failing

Comment: If it's not complete, it doesn't serve as example, so it isn't a minimal example either. Again, read the posting guidelines, they explain how to create a minimal example.

Comment: sounds like a job for a debugger...

Comment: Let's try again. Do a *shallow swap*. If you have two objects o1, o2 with members m1, m2, ..., mn you swap them by swap(o1.m1, o2.m1), ... swap(o1.mn, o2.mn). It doesn't matter if some of these members are pointers to lists or trees or graphs or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: don't reinvent the wheel. `std::list` is well tested and already implements `std::swap()`. Writing your own list is just useful for education purpose.

Anyway, don't swap the elements themself, but the pointers to them. Your list probably contains a pointer to the first and the last node. Swap these pointers, and maybe some metadate, like size, and you are done.

Comment: Its part of my homework assignment to implement a linked list by myself. Do you know why I would be getting an error simply because one is a pointer and the other is a reference?

Comment: Do you mean the reference in the call to `swap`? How couls that be an issue? You should swap the pointers to `begin` and `end` nodes, not those to the list. Please take your time and think about what that means and why it works. Write it down or draw a chart, if that helps you. It will soon be obvious to you, when you try to avoid being hectic. Its not magic.